# Show: $\sum_{n=1}^{k}\sum_{m=n}^{k}\int_m^{m+1}f(x)dx=\sum_{m=1}^{k}m \int_m^{m+1}f(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, summation, proof-explanation

What I understand is that $\sum_{n=1}^{k}\sum_{m=n}^{k}\int_m^{m+1}f(x)dx$  means summing $\int_m^{m+1}f(x)dx$ from $1$ to $k$ twice, since we see that  $\sum_{n=1}^{k}=\sum_{m=1}^{k}$ since, $m=n$, but then how we get the identity given above? I am confused!

Please show elaborately that-

$$\sum_{n=1}^{k}\sum_{m=n}^{k}\int_m^{m+1}f(x)dx$$
$$=\sum_{m=1}^{k}m \int_m^{m+1}f(x)dx$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just a matter of definition.
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{k} \sum_{m=n}^{k} \int_m^{m+1} f(x)dx
$$
Expand along the first sum:
$$
\left( \sum_{m=1}^{k} \int_m^{m+1} f(x)dx \right)
+ \left( \sum_{m=2}^{k} \int_m^{m+1} f(x)dx \right)
+ \cdots
+ \left( \sum_{m=k}^{k} \int_m^{m+1} f(x)dx \right)
$$
Write each term in parentheses as a new line, and expand the sum:
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
\int_1^{2} f(x)dx & + & \int_2^{3} f(x)dx & + & \cdots & + & \int_k^{k+1} f(x)dx \\
& + & \int_2^{3} f(x)dx & + & \cdots & + & \int_k^{k+1} f(x)dx \\
&&&& \ddots && \vdots \\
&&&&& + & \int_k^{k+1} f(x)dx
\end{array}
$$
Now count the number of each integral:
$$
1 \cdot \left( \int_1^{2} f(x)dx \right)
+ 2 \cdot \left( \int_2^{3} f(x)dx \right)
+ \cdots
+ k \cdot \left( \int_k^{k+1} f(x)dx \right)
$$
Recombine using sigma notation:
$$
\sum_{m=1}^{k} m \int_m^{m+1} f(x)dx
$$

Answer (score 2):

With $a_m = \int_m^{m+1} f(x)\,dx$, the sum can be written as

$$\sum_{n=1}^k\sum_{m=1}^k \mathbf{1}_{m\geqslant n}a_m = \sum_{m=1}^k \left(\sum_{n=1}^k \mathbf{1}_{m\geqslant n}\right) a_m = \sum_{m=1}^k m a_m$$

Comment: The indicator function $\mathbf{1}_{m\geqslant n} =1$ if $m \geqslant n$ and $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

In general for a sequence $\{a_m\}$:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{k}\sum_{m=n}^{k} a_m =\sum_{m=1}^{k}m a_m.$$

That can be proven by induction on $k$.

Replace $a_m$ with $\int_m^{m+1}f(x)$... and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Another proof without induction

**How many points is there in each horizontal line?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can write the index region conveniently to better see what's going on.

> We obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^k\sum_{m=n}^k\int_{m}^{m+1}f(x)\,dx&=\sum_{\color{blue}{1\leq n\leq m\leq k}}\int_{m}^{m+1}f(x)\,dx\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{m=1}^k\sum_{n=1}^m\int_{m}^{m+1}f(x)\,dx\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{m=1}^k\int_{m}^{m+1}f(x)\,dx\sum_{n=1}^m1\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{m=1}^km\int_{m}^{m+1}f(x)\,dx
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- (1): The inequality chain shows the relationship of the indices $n$ and $m$,
- (2): enabling us to exchange the sums easily.
- (3): The integral does not depend on the index $n$ and can be factored out.